# GAE API explorer doesn't show APIs, appears to be stuck loading

Tags: api, google-app-engine, http, https, web.xml

This happens both on local deserver and when deployed. I was successfully able to use the API explorer with the guestbook tutorial, but now that I've made my own project and am trying to access the first API I have written it never appears. The yellow "Loading..." box next to the search bar never disappears.

I've looked at various solutions online but none have done the trick.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me to try?

Sorry for the broad question!

Comment: I have had this problem so many times with AE!

Comment: After update/first upload it takes some time (minutes) before your API is available in the API explorer. Also, do you see any indication in the logs suggesting endpoint update was unsuccessful / any exceptions around the time of an update? Does the issue persists in the incognito mode?

Comment: I solved this issue by removing '1.' from the url.

https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://1.YOUR_APP.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I only got this issue when I typed in the URL myself, if I visit localhost:8080 where I am hosting the application and click on the link to the API Explorer then they all load.